# NSTextField Troubles

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield, osx-mountain-lion

I have a NSTextField in my MainMenu nib...
[image]
The selector for this text field is connected to the AppDelegate. I have also set the action to be sent upon the end of editing. Like so...

[image]

I have no idea why, but the action is only being sent when the user hits return. "Sent on end editing" has never behaved like this before. Any ideas why I'm having this odd behavior? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: How else are you trying to end editing?  Does tab not work?

Comment: @rdelmar Tab does work but I've had different behavior in the past. Usually the selector got called a few times every second, as long as the string had changed. I could type "this is a string" and the selector would be called 5-6 times. Is that not normal?

Comment: I've never seen that behavior that you're describing with an action method for a text field.  You can get the controlTextDidChange: delegate method called each time you type a character, but action methods are only called on end editing (tab, return, or clicking on another control that takes the focus) or on return -- as far as I remember, it's always been that way.

Comment: Wow that's really weird. Thank you for your help, rdelmar.